# How do I set the value of an XSLT output based on conditional processing of two sibling nodes in an XML input (Active Directory User attributes)?

Tags: xml, xslt

**USE CASE:**
I have a fax application process that retrieves User objects from Microsoft Active Directory Domain Services and maps the AD User attributes into associated user attributes in the application.

**REQUIREMENTS:**

- Populate a SINGLE `<value></value>` node under an `<attr name="facsimileTelephoneNumber"></attr>` node in the XML output.
- Set the `<value/>` based on the final result of the condition of multiple nodes of the XML input.

**NOTE:** I'm not sure what the XSLT Engine is.  The processor is built in to the fax application.

**FLOW OF CONDITIONS:**

- If the  of `<attr name="facsimileTelephoneNumber">` is NOT an empty string, then

  - Remove everything but integers and put the `<value>` under `<attr name="PersonalFaxNumber">`.
- If the `<value>` of `<attr name="facsimileTelephoneNumber">` IS an empty string, then

  - Process the `<value>` nodes under the `<attr name="proxyAddresses">` node.
- In the `<attr name="proxyAddresses">` node, find the first  with a string that starts with "did:" (optionally) followed by 10 digits.
- If a value is found, then

  - Remove "did:" from the string and put the  under `<attr name="PersonalFaxNumber">`
  - Discard all other `<value>` nodes under `<attr name="proxyAddresses">`.
- Otherwise, the `<value>` under `<attr name="PersonalFaxNumber">` is the string "8885551234".

**PROBLEMS:** My attempts at XSL coding always result in

- Multiple `<attr name="PersonalFaxNumber">` outputs
- Remaining proxy addresses in the output.

**SAMPLE INPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<syncRequest xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" source="ActiveDirectory" >
  <userAddRequest source="ActiveDirectory" guid="1234abc567890d11e22fa3b45c6789de">
    <attr name="sAMAccountName">
      <value>johndoe</value>
    </attr>
    <attr name="facsimileTelephoneNumber">
      <value>111-555-1234</value>
    </attr>
    <attr name="proxyAddresses">
      <value>did:2225551111</value>
      <value>smtp:johndoe@mydomain.com</value>
    </attr>
  </userAddRequest>
  <userAddRequest source="ActiveDirectory" guid="4321cba098765a99b88cd7e65f9876ab">
    <attr name="sAMAccountName">
      <value>joeschmoe</value>
    </attr>
    <attr name="facsimileTelephoneNumber">
      <value></value>
    </attr>
    <attr name="proxyAddresses">
      <value>did:2225554321</value>
      <value>smtp:joeschmoe@mydomain.com</value>
    </attr>
  </userAddRequest>
    <attr name="sAMAccountName">
      <value>janedoe</value>
    </attr>
  <userAddRequest source="ActiveDirectory" guid="5555cba123123a45b45cd4e45f4545cd">
    <attr name="facsimileTelephoneNumber">
      <value></value>
    </attr>
    <attr name="proxyAddresses">
      <value></value>
      <value>smtp:janedoe@mydomain.com</value>
    </attr>
  </userAddRequest>
</syncRequest>
```

**MY ATTEMPTED XSL** - DERIVED FROM ALL MY READING AND EXPERIMENTATION:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:rf="urn:rightfax-sync-schema"
    xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="rf"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- "userID" is a required attribute -->
  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='sAMAccountName']">
    <attr name="UserID">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rf:attr[@name='facsimileTelephoneNumber'] | rf:attr[@name='proxyAddresses']/*[starts-with(.,'did:')][1]">
    <attr name="RouteCode">
        <value>100</value>
    </attr>
    <attr name="PersonalFaxNum">
      <value>
       <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="compare(normalize-space(.),'') != 0">
                 <xsl:variable name="cleanNumber" select="translate(normalize-space(.), 'did: .-,()', '')"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$cleanNumber"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>8885551234</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </value>
    </attr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT RESULTS...**

When 'facsimileTelephoneNumber' contains a string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="UserID">johndoe</attr>
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="PersonalFaxNum">
   <value>1115551234</value>
</attr>
    
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="PersonalFaxNum">
   <value>2225551111</value>
</attr>
      smtp:johndoe@mydomain.com
```

When 'facsimileTelephoneNumber' in empty and 'proxyAddressess' has a value node starting with "DID:" (I haven't figured out how to check for "followed by 10 digits, but that's a total bonus.  I can work with the DID: part.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="UserID">joeschmoe</attr>
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="PersonalFaxNum">
   <value>8885551234</value>
</attr>
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="PersonalFaxNum">
   <value>2225554321</value>
</attr>
      smtp:joeschmoe@mydomain.com
```

When neither 'facsimileTelephoneNumber' nor 'proxyAddresses' have matching  nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="UserID">janedoe</attr>
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="PersonalFaxNum">
   <value>8885551234</value>
</attr>
    
      
      smtp:janedoe@mydomain.com
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

**- CASE 1:**

```
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="UserID">johndoe</attr>
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="PersonalFaxNum">
  <value>1115551234</value>
</attr>
```

**- CASE 2:**

```
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="UserID">johndoe</attr>
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="PersonalFaxNum"> 
  <value>2225554321</value>
</attr>
```

**- CASE 3:**

```
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="UserID">johndoe</attr>
<attr xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema" name="PersonalFaxNum"> 
  <value>8885551234</value>
</attr>
```

Comment: ADDENDUM:  I do not know how to determine the version of XSLT being used, or supported by the application.

Comment: Can you post what the expected output is if the input you posted is processed? Which XSLT engine are you using?

Comment: First time posting.  The editor output removed XML element names I enclosed in &lt; and &gt; characters.

Comment: You're showing a sample input, but not what the output should be?

Comment: @Sebastien I edited the original post.  Hopefully it's more clear?!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSL does what you specified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:rf="urn:rightfax-sync-schema"
    xmlns="urn:rightfax-sync-schema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="rf"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="rf:userAddRequest">
        <userAddRequest source="{@source}" guid="{@guid}">
            <attr name="UserID"><xsl:value-of select="rf:attr[@name='sAMAccountName']/rf:value" /></attr>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="rf:attr[@name='facsimileTelephoneNumber']/rf:value!=''">
                    <attr name="PersonalFaxNum">
                      <value><xsl:value-of select="rf:attr[@name='facsimileTelephoneNumber']/rf:value" /></value>
                    </attr>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains(rf:attr[@name='proxyAddresses']/rf:value,'did')">
                            <attr name="PersonalFaxNum">
                                <value><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(rf:attr[@name='proxyAddresses']/rf:value,'did:')" /></value>
                            </attr>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <attr name="PersonalFaxNum">
                              <value>8885551234</value>
                            </attr>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                
                </xsl:otherwise>
                
            </xsl:choose>
        </userAddRequest>
    </xsl:template>

    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that in your example input, you have this node included

```
    <attr name="sAMAccountName">
        <value>janedoe</value>
    </attr>
```

, but not wrapped in a

```
    <userAddRequest />
```

I'm not sure if this intended. It will not be processed according to your rules as it is.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance.  I learned alot.  I especially learned that providing the full context might mean fewer caveats.  At the same time, I shouldn't expect the SO community to do all my work for me.  Your answer got me over a big hurdle, and some more research and testing we have been able to implement a XSLT that performs all the additional functions we needed.